# Cast error on a Kotlin class that extends a Java class

Tags: java, kotlin, casting

I have a Java project that uses an internal company library made in Kotlin. In this library, I have a Kotlin class that extends the `Feign.Builder`. This is how the decompiled code looks like

```java
public final class CustomizedFeign public constructor() {
    public final class Builder public constructor() : feign.Feign.Builder {
       ...
    }
}
```

And this is how the original Kotlin code looks like:

```java
class CustomizedFeign {
    class Builder : Feign.Builder() {
       ... 
    }
}
```

When I try to cast the `CustomizedFeign.Builder` class to `Feign.Builder` in my Java project

```java
final Feign.Builder builder = (Feign.Builder) new CustomizedFeign.Builder();
```

IntelliJ shows an error:
`Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'CustomizedFeign.Builder' to 'feign.Feign.Builder'`

I don't get why I'm having this error. In java, you can cast from a child class to a parent class without problems. In this case, `CustomizedFeign.Builder` is a subtype of `Feign.Builder`, so I should be allowed to cast them... I guess the "Kotlin factor" has something to do with this error.

EDIT:
I know I shouldn't need to do an explicit cast. If I don't do it:

```java
final Feign.Builder builder = new CustomizedFeign.Builder();
```

The error is different but, at the end of the day, the outcome is the same:

```
Required type:
feign.Feign.Builder
Provided:
CustomizedFeign.Builder
```

EDIT 2:
Somehow I think this is related to trying to do this in a Java project. If I try this code in a Kotlin project, I don't get any error:

```
val builder: feign.Feign.Builder = CustomizedFeign.Builder()
```

Comment: if it's a subtype you don't need to cast

Comment: There may be some inconsistency between your code and your explanations like ` I try to cast the  CustomizedFeign class to Feign.Builder`. However `CustomizedFeign` does not inherits from Feign.Builder. Please share the actual code.

Comment: Apologies, it was a mistake in the message. I've fixed it ;-)

Comment: Make sure you don't have two distinct `Feign` classes. This code should just work, even without casting.